# SendGrid Template does not contain required placeholders

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, twilio-api

i'm trying to use the Email verify service via send grid and after i'm write all the placeholders i'm getting this error: "SendGrid Template does not contain required placeholders", and I can't find any solution.

Can someone guide me with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable the "Template Engine" read access for your API key. You can do so here: https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys. Make sure it is read access only (i.e. the slider is in the middle).

Comment: This was the answer! Thanks ton!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I used `{{{ code }}}` to load the dynamic data. In my case, its OTP. So I replaced `{{{ code }}}` with `{{{twilio_code}}}` and the problem was resolved.

Comment: This was the answer.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/email

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the following applies : https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/6554095919003-Error-SendGrid-Template-does-not-contain-required-placeholders-

```
Cause

This error message usually due to the SendGrid Dynamic template missing
at least one of the following placeholders:

- {{twilio_code}}
- {{twilio_message}}
- {{twilio_message_without_code}}
```